# In R, how do I run st_convex_hull function on point sf object?

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm trying to get a convex hull of point features in R.

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)
nc <- st_centroid(st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")))
qtm(nc)

ch <- st_convex_hull(nc) 
qtm(ch)

identical(nc, ch)
```

I'd expect the `st_convex_hull` to contain polygon with convex hull. However it returns points that are not identical. How can I get the polygon instead?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to union the points into `MULTIPOINTS`

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)
nc <- st_centroid(st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")))
qtm(nc)

ch <- st_convex_hull(st_union(nc)) 
qtm(ch)
```

Comment: Can this be applied to grouped data where an hull is generated for each group?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be.