# Convert sf to unmarked ppp

Tags: r, r-sf, spatstat

I wish to convert an `sf` object to an unmarked `ppp`. (Conversion from `sf` to `ppp` is now supported, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64158441/7114709).)

```
library(sf)

#Initialise sf object
pp <- structure(list(X = c(959207.877070254, 959660.734838225, 951483.685462513,  951527.767554883, 958310.673042469, 950492.05212104, 959660.734838225,  959207.877070254, 960500.020456073, 959660.734838225), Y = c(1944457.42827898,  1955543.76027363, 1939982.16629396, 1940216.55143212, 1954704.68186897,  1951434.68524296, 1955543.76027363, 1944457.42827898, 1955292.64874361,  1955543.76027363), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(959207.877070254,  1944457.42827898), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959660.734838225,  1955543.76027363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(951483.685462513,  1939982.16629396), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(951527.767554883,  1940216.55143212), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(958310.673042469,  1954704.68186897), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(950492.05212104,  1951434.68524296), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959660.734838225,  1955543.76027363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959207.877070254,  1944457.42827898), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(960500.020456073,  1955292.64874361), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959660.734838225,  1955543.76027363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT",  "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 950492.05212104,  ymin = 1939982.16629396, xmax = 960500.020456073, ymax = 1955543.76027363 ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:5179",      wkt = "PROJCRS[\"Korea 2000 / Unified CS\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"Korea 2000\",\n        DATUM[\"Geocentric datum of Korea\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4737]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Korea Unified Belt\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",38,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",127.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",1000000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",2000000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"northing (X)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"easting (Y)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"Korea, Republic of (South Korea)\"],\n        BBOX[28.6,122.71,40.27,134.28]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",5179]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(4177L,  15721L, 21365L, 21973L, 24836L, 59359L, 66313L, 70379L, 83277L,  90828L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(X = NA_integer_,  Y = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity" ), class = "factor"))

library(spatstat)

#Convert to ppp format: method 1
pp1 <- as.ppp(pp)
#Warning message:
#In as.ppp.sf(pp) : only first attribute column is used for marks
pp1 <- unmark(pp1)

#Convert to ppp format: method 2
pp2 <- as.ppp(st_coordinates(pp), st_convex_hull(st_union(pp)))
#Warning message:
#data contain duplicated points

identical(pp1, pp2)
[1] FALSE
```

The first method requires marks and I haven't been able to find out how to turn that off (specifying `marks=NULL` does not work). I remove marks afterwards but that is a workaround.

The second method is probably wrong, considering the warning, although I based it on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51719497/7114709). The 2 outputs are not identical.

Is any of these methods correct? Why does method 2 produce duplicated points? Is there a more straightforward method of conversion, with no workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that the following answer works for every version of `spatstat`, but I think that if you want to generate an unmarked `ppp` object, you should run

```r
# packages
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(sf)
  library(spatstat)
})

# Initialise sf object
pp <- structure(list(X = c(959207.877070254, 959660.734838225, 951483.685462513,  951527.767554883, 958310.673042469, 950492.05212104, 959660.734838225,  959207.877070254, 960500.020456073, 959660.734838225), Y = c(1944457.42827898,  1955543.76027363, 1939982.16629396, 1940216.55143212, 1954704.68186897,  1951434.68524296, 1955543.76027363, 1944457.42827898, 1955292.64874361,  1955543.76027363), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(959207.877070254,  1944457.42827898), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959660.734838225,  1955543.76027363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(951483.685462513,  1939982.16629396), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(951527.767554883,  1940216.55143212), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(958310.673042469,  1954704.68186897), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(950492.05212104,  1951434.68524296), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959660.734838225,  1955543.76027363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959207.877070254,  1944457.42827898), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(960500.020456073,  1955292.64874361), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959660.734838225,  1955543.76027363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT",  "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 950492.05212104,  ymin = 1939982.16629396, xmax = 960500.020456073, ymax = 1955543.76027363 ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:5179",      wkt = "PROJCRS[\"Korea 2000 / Unified CS\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"Korea 2000\",\n        DATUM[\"Geocentric datum of Korea\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4737]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Korea Unified Belt\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",38,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",127.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",1000000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",2000000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"northing (X)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"easting (Y)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"Korea, Republic of (South Korea)\"],\n        BBOX[28.6,122.71,40.27,134.28]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",5179]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(4177L,  15721L, 21365L, 21973L, 24836L, 59359L, 66313L, 70379L, 83277L,  90828L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(X = NA_integer_,  Y = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity" ), class = "factor"))

# Convert to ppp format: method 1
(pp1 <- as.ppp(st_geometry(pp)))
#> Planar point pattern: 10 points
#> window: rectangle = [950492.1, 960500] x [1939982.2, 1955543.8] units
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The two methods that you present are not equivalent because the `as.ppp.sfc` function defined in the `sf` package uses a rectangular `owin` object:

```r
# packages
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(sf)
  library(spatstat)
})

#Initialise sf object
pp <- structure(list(X = c(959207.877070254, 959660.734838225, 951483.685462513,  951527.767554883, 958310.673042469, 950492.05212104, 959660.734838225,  959207.877070254, 960500.020456073, 959660.734838225), Y = c(1944457.42827898,  1955543.76027363, 1939982.16629396, 1940216.55143212, 1954704.68186897,  1951434.68524296, 1955543.76027363, 1944457.42827898, 1955292.64874361,  1955543.76027363), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(959207.877070254,  1944457.42827898), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959660.734838225,  1955543.76027363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(951483.685462513,  1939982.16629396), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(951527.767554883,  1940216.55143212), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(958310.673042469,  1954704.68186897), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(950492.05212104,  1951434.68524296), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959660.734838225,  1955543.76027363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959207.877070254,  1944457.42827898), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(960500.020456073,  1955292.64874361), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(959660.734838225,  1955543.76027363), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT",  "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 950492.05212104,  ymin = 1939982.16629396, xmax = 960500.020456073, ymax = 1955543.76027363 ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:5179",      wkt = "PROJCRS[\"Korea 2000 / Unified CS\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"Korea 2000\",\n        DATUM[\"Geocentric datum of Korea\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4737]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Korea Unified Belt\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",38,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",127.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",1000000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",2000000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"northing (X)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"easting (Y)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"Korea, Republic of (South Korea)\"],\n        BBOX[28.6,122.71,40.27,134.28]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",5179]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(4177L,  15721L, 21365L, 21973L, 24836L, 59359L, 66313L, 70379L, 83277L,  90828L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(X = NA_integer_,  Y = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity" ), class = "factor"))

# Convert to ppp format: method 1
(pp1 <- as.ppp(st_geometry(pp)))
#> Planar point pattern: 10 points
#> window: rectangle = [950492.1, 960500] x [1939982.2, 1955543.8] units

# Method 2
(pp2 <- as.ppp(
  X = st_coordinates(pp), 
  W = as.owin(st_bbox(pp))
))
#> Warning: data contain duplicated points
#> Planar point pattern: 10 points
#> window: rectangle = [950492.1, 960500] x [1939982.2, 1955543.8] units

identical(pp1, pp2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Moreover, the first method returns no warning message since the authors set `check = FALSE`.

```r
anyDuplicated(pp1)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

See [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/blob/b639ec375b19e57fcae3dbaa4a6cdbab3d76f43c/R/spatstat.R#L110-L140) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The two commands should give the same result. Getting different results is a temporary problem caused by recent changes to the `spatstat` package.

(These changes break some assumptions made by the packages `sf`, `maptools` and `sp`, causing the second command to fail to find the correct method for `as.owin`, so that it defaults to a rectangular window).

There's nothing wrong with the first approach. The data `pp` contain mark values, so `as.ppp` handles the marks, with a warning that it only used the first column. If you don't want the marks, just use `unmark` afterward.

The warning you get in the second approach tells you that some of the data points are at the same location. You don't get this warning in the first approach because the points at the same location have different mark values.

Warnings are not errors. Both these approaches are OK apart from the temporary problem with the dispatch of `as.owin`.

I suggest you use the first approach.

If you really need to use the second approach, you'll need to update all these packages, and in the case of `spatstat`, install the development version available at [the github repository](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat).
If that still causes trouble, please wait a week or so until the completed package updates for all four packages are published on CRAN.

Comment: My mistake, as I hadn't yet grokked the retrospectively obvious fact that the geometry column is sufficient in `sf` to locate points, so I was uselessly duplicating coordinates X and Y into separate columns, which `spatstat` then proceeds to interpret as marks...