# How to get outline of sf object?

Tags: r, r-sf

I'm looking for a way to extract/infer a polygon from some sf object, that describes an outline that encompasses valid data. I only have limited experience with sf, so any advice aside from an answer is appreciated too.

Let's say I have some data in some unusual projection.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

world <- st_as_sf(rworldmap::getMap(resolution = "low"))

tworld <- st_transform(world, "+proj=igh")
plot(tworld, max.plot = 1)
```

[image]

I can get the graticule of that just fine (through for the IGH projection in particular, maybe not the nicest graticule).

```r
grat <- st_graticule(tworld)
plot(grat, max.plot = 1)
```

[image]

But how do I get the outline that encompasses the data in a reliable way? I have thought about just re-projecting a long/lat rectangle. But does that also work when the initial geometry isn't a (complete) map of the world? If the initial data are just cartesian XY-coordinates, I should perhaps just get the X and Y range instead to form a rectangle.

```r
p <- st_polygon(
  list(matrix(c(-180, -180, 180, 180, -180, -90, 90, 90, -90, -90), 5))
)
p <- st_segmentize(p, 1)
p <- st_sfc(p)
st_crs(p) <- 4326 # long/lat coords
proj_p <- st_transform(p, "+proj=igh")
plot(proj_p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It seems like st_bbox() should do what you are looking for

Comment: For cartesian coordinates that'll do just fine, but I'm looking for an outline that essentially connects the line ends of the graticule into some sensible shape.

Comment: `grat_hull <- st_convex_hull(st_union(grat))` [where I  saw it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718839/in-r-how-do-i-run-st-convex-hull-function-on-point-sf-object), the `st_union` part wouldn't have occurred to me...but I was thinking convex hull.

Comment: Thanks that seems like a step in the right direction. Using `st_graticule() |> st_union() |> st_convex_hull()` does give a sensible shape.

Comment: I'm curious @teunbrand, what project or package are you working on now? You're contributions to the ggplot-iverse (`ggh4x` and here on SO) are great, what's next?

Comment: This is for a contribution to ggplot2 itself to give proper curved axes to `coord_sf()` for projections that don't reach the edge of the panels ([#2985](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2985)). I know a bit about axes, but not so much {sf}, so I thought I'd inquire here.

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but in `{shotGroups}` https://github.com/dwoll/shotGroups/tree/master/R there are `getMinBBox` / `Circle` / `Ellipse` functions, which might be somehow useful.